# How to access array from another file Next Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I'm creating a Quiz App. There are two pages `takeQuiz.js` and `result.js`. I want to collect mcqs data from `takeQuiz.js` in `result.js`.I using `router.replace()` so user can't go back one they submit quiz.
**takeQuiz.js**

```
mcqsData = [
{quesId:1,correct:'Option A',selectedOption:'Option C'},
{quesId:1,correct:'Option C',selectedOption:'Option B'},
{quesId:1,correct:'Option D',selectedOption:'Option D'},
]
```

How can I access this array in `result.js`?. I tried `import data from './takeQuiz.js'` but it return `undefined`

Comment: did you use the export keyword for `mcqsData`  in your code?

Comment: Like `export mcqsData` or `export.mcqsData`

Comment: if you use `export mcqsData`, you need to import like this: `import {mcqsData as data} from './takeQuiz.js'`

Comment: thanks it worked

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the `export` statement in front of your array. Without it, the import statement has nothing to grab.

```
export mcqsData = [
{quesId:1,correct:'Option A',selectedOption:'Option C'},
{quesId:1,correct:'Option C',selectedOption:'Option B'},
{quesId:1,correct:'Option D',selectedOption:'Option D'},
]
```

then in your main *result.js* file, import the name of your array. `import {mcqsData} from './takeQuiz.js'`

More info can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export